# How to validate JWT using a hardcoded public key in tests and get the "real" public key from an identity provider in production?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, openid

I have a C# ASP.NET Core web service running in Azure. Users are expected to authenticate themselves using a JSON Web Token (JWT). I need to validate that incoming JWTs are valid. Among other things, I need to validate that they are signed with the expected public key.

For my integration tests, I spin up a local instance of my service using **Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer**. In these tests I would like to be able to create my own JWTs on the fly, so here I want to be able to specify a public key which my service should use to validate the JWTs.

For my production and staging environments, the public key should match the public key of the relevant identity provider.

Today I store the public keys (modulus and exponent) in my **appsettings.json** files for all environments. But I would like to move away from this. In production and staging, I would like to get the public key automatically from the identity provider. A colleague advised me to do this in my **Startup.cs**:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
services
    .AddAuthentication(auth => {
        auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
        options.Authority = _configuration["Auth:Endpoint"];
        options.Audience = _configuration["JwtAuthentication:Audience"];
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new() {
            RoleClaimType = "role",
            NameClaimType = "sub"
        };
    });
```

This is probably nice for production, but not so nice for integration tests where I want full control over the JWTs.

Of course I could use some kind of feature toggle so the above only gets used in production, and in integration tests I use some other JWT validation code where I can inject my own public key (like what I have today). But then my tests wouldn't be testing the production code, which is unfortunate. I would need to do extra steps to test the JWT validation code.

Ideally I would like to use the snippet above *and* be able to override by injecting my own public key.

There might also be an easy way to manually get the public key from the identity provider, but a quick search doesn't reveal how I might do that.

Alternatively, maybe I could host my own tiny identity provider, but I have no idea how difficult that would be.

What solution can you recommend?

Comment: You mention getting the key automatically at startup. I presume you are hitting some kind of jwk endpoint (i.e https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517)
If this is the case then it might be a good idea to abstract that call behind a service. Then the service that calls the URL in production can also be mocked for unit testing to always return your test value. The same would hold true no matter where it gets the public key from. e.g. if it gets the key from a cache then you can mock that cache interface when unit testing.

Comment: ignore my above. it'd make sense if you were manually resolving the key and passing it in to the validator, but I see this is all abstracted away from you. I see some answers floating around that use preprocessor directives but personally I don't like that so I don't want to recommend it. hopefully somebody has a good option. surely we should be able to intercept and mock this in a unit test... hopefully